# Escaping square bracket in bash inside a string for an if

Tags: bash, escaping

I'm trying to do a simple `if` statement but one of the string contains square brackets.

I've tried with `\ ' " +` and everything came in my mind.

I've basically this:

```
if [ $MESSAGE = "username [$USERNAME] is already taken" ]
```

and in this case I would like to throw an error message.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Quote $MESSAGE as well. If that variable does contain a [, it will affect the parsing.

```
if [ "$MESSAGE" = "username [$USERNAME] is already taken" ]
```

Comment: So simple and effective! Thanks!