# How to compare strings containing a square bracket in Bash

Tags: string, bash, brackets

I am searching for a comparison with square brackes in bash.

Situation: I have a hosts file that contains hostnames that looks like

```
[debian]
ansible
host
names

[centos]
more
hosts
```

now I want to scan all host's ssh keys (first echo, later use ssh-keyscan):

```
while read hostName
do
  if [[ $hostName != "" ]] &&  [[ $hostName != "\[*" ]] ; then
    echo $hostName
    #ssh-keyscan $hostName
  fi
done < hosts
```

while `[[ $hostName != "" ]]` does it's job the part containing the comparison for square brackets `[[ $hostName 
!= "\[*" ]]` does not. Atm the result looks like this:

```
[debian]
ansible
host
names
[centos]
more
hosts
```

I want it to look like:

```
ansible
host
names
more
hosts
```

While e.g. [How to compare strings in Bash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2237080/how-to-compare-strings-in-bash) covers the general topic, it does not cover my question. Also I'd like to avoid using sed or other string replacement methods before I can compare the string -if possible. Does anybody know how to compare square brackets in a string in bash?

Also not working: 
[this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11419668/escaping-square-bracket-in-bash-inside-a-string-for-an-if), adapted comparison (maybe I adapted it the wrong way?):

```
if [[ $hostName != "" ]] && [ "$hostName" != "*[*" ]
```

Comment: Looks like another answer on the first page you linked will help: https://stackoverflow.com/a/16263820/1354854. The solution is `if [[ $hostName != *"["* ]]`. The wildcard must be _outside_ the quotes, which is not intuitive, or just unquoted entirely since you're using `[[`.

Comment: Huh, did not see that one. OK that works, thanks a lot :) .

Answer (score 1):

This does what you need and is POSIX compatible:

```
while read hostName
do
  if [ "$hostName" ] && [ "$hostName" = "${hostName#[}" ] ; then
    echo $hostName
    #ssh-keyscan $hostName
  fi
done < hosts
```

Answer (score 0):

Alternative #1:

```
while read hostName
do
  if [[ $hostName != "" ]] &&  [[ $hostName != *"["* ]] ; then
  echo "$hostName"
  #ssh-keyscan $hostName
fi
done < hosts
```

Alternative #2:

```
grep -v '^\[.*\]$'  hosts | while read hostName
do
  if [[ $hostName != "" ]] ; then
  echo "$hostName"
  #ssh-keyscan $hostName
fi
done
```

Alternative #3:

```
grep -v '^\[.*\]$' hosts | grep -v '^[ \t]*$' | while read hostName
do
  echo "$hostName"
  #ssh-keyscan $hostName
done
```